# ActiveX in VC++ without MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, activex

I'm wondering if it is possible to create an ActiveX control without using the MFC ActiveX that is provided in VS2010? I prefer to do the code entirely from scratch without any predefined or generated content. All the guides on ActiveX are based on using MFC and all the generated code is quite confusing and hard to get a grasp on and fully understand.

I am also not very used to the MFC syntax, I am looking for something akin to standard c++ against the win32 api. As I understand it, ActiveX components can be developed in other languages aswell apart from MFC, such as C. I would like to use standard C/C++ but I can't find any resources on how to do a very minimal ActiveX from scratch.

Hope I made it clear enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Drop the 'standard C++' requirement and this becomes a *lot* easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True, you don't need MFC (or any other framework) to develop ActiveX controls but there's a good reason you're not finding examples on how to do it without. **It's incredibly tough to do so.** My suggestion is to take the time to learn a framework that supports ActiveX and implement the ActiveX control. It will take you much, much longer to go without.

Besides, if you go without you will soon discover how much [boiler plate code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_%28text%29#Boilerplate_code) is involved. All the boilerplate alone, IMO, is worth using MFC and the wizards that generate all the scaffolding code.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding all the generated code, everything is easier to grasp if you create it all by yourself. It is offtopic but do you know a good resource for understanding the generated code stuff?

Comment: There will be no single resource. ActiveX is a mix of several technologies, of which the core is COM. There is also OLE Controls, MIDL and the dozen or so interfaces that an ActiveX control has to support. I would start by reading the wikis for each of those terms.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is to use ATL. Making an ActiveX control from scratch without any frameworks is far from trivial.

Answer (score 2):

ATL and WTL, I love those frameworks, no MFC mess, small executables and very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

The old VB 6.0 was the easiest best environment for Active-X controls I have seen. Also now "free" I believe. The only problem being that they always had a "form" or GUI presence. So for non-visible controls a bit of a pain. Anyway checkout these links:
[Basic Principles of ActiveX Controls:](http://www.nku.edu/~manningd/controls.htm)
[Visual Basic Programming Examples](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~saul/vb_examples/)